# IManyToManyCollectionInstance convention creating extra table

Tags: c#, postgresql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a Fluent NHibernate convention-based mapping with a Many-to-Many relationship between my `StockPurchase` entity and my `StockSale` entity.

I created the following convention:

```
public class ManyToManyLinkedTableConvention : IHasManyToManyConvention
{
    public void Apply(FluentNHibernate.Conventions.Instances.IManyToManyCollectionInstance instance)
    {
        var naming = new NamingStrategy();
        if (StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase.Compare(instance.EntityType.Name, instance.OtherSide.EntityType.Name) > 0)
        {
            instance.Table(naming.Quote(
                string.Format(
                    "{0}To{1}",
                    Inflector.Inflector.Pluralize(instance.EntityType.Name),
                    Inflector.Inflector.Pluralize(instance.ChildType.Name))));
            instance.Not.Inverse();
        }
        else
        {
            instance.Inverse();
        }
    }
}
```

When I use the hbm2ddl function, it builds the table exactly as I want it:

```
CREATE TABLE "StockSalesToStockPurchases"
(
  stocksale_id uuid NOT NULL,
  stockpurchase_id uuid NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT fkee886e07285f29f1 FOREIGN KEY (stockpurchase_id)
      REFERENCES "StockPurchases" (stockpurchaseid) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fkee886e073b8be3d9 FOREIGN KEY (stocksale_id)
      REFERENCES "StockSales" (stocksaleid) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
);
```

... bizarrely, though, it creates a second table as well:

```
CREATE TABLE stockpurchasestostocksales
(
  stockpurchase_id uuid NOT NULL,
  stocksale_id uuid NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT fk396e0343285f29f1 FOREIGN KEY (stockpurchase_id)
      REFERENCES "StockPurchases" (stockpurchaseid) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk396e03433b8be3d9 FOREIGN KEY (stocksale_id)
      REFERENCES "StockSales" (stocksaleid) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
);
```

Why is it doing this, and how do I stop it?

Answer (score 2):

OK, I found out how to do this.  Someone let me know if there's a better way.

```
public class ManyToManyLinkedTableConvention : IHasManyToManyConvention
{
    public void Apply(IManyToManyCollectionInstance instance)
    {
        var naming = new NamingStrategy();
        string firstName;
        string secondName;

        if (StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase.Compare(instance.EntityType.Name, instance.OtherSide.EntityType.Name) >
            0)
        {
            firstName = instance.EntityType.Name;
            secondName = instance.OtherSide.EntityType.Name;
        }
        else
        {
            secondName = instance.EntityType.Name;
            firstName = instance.OtherSide.EntityType.Name;
            instance.Not.Inverse();
        }

        instance.Table(naming.Quote(
            string.Format(
                "{0}To{1}",
                Inflector.Inflector.Pluralize(firstName),
                Inflector.Inflector.Pluralize(secondName))));
    }
}
```